# Best way to map/join two autogenerated enums

Tags: c++, enums, type-conversion

What is the best C++ **(not C++11)** way of joining two enums from autogenerated class similar to one presented below:

```
namespace A {
  namespace B { ...
    class CarInfo {
      public:
      enum State {   // basically same enums defined in different classes
        Running,
        Stopped,
        Broken
      };
    };

    class BikeInfo {
      public:
      enum State {   // basically same enums defined in different classes
        Running,
        Stopped,
        Broken
      };
    };
  }
}
```

What is needed is unified enum State for both classes that is seen to outside world alongside with safe type conversion.

The best and probably most straightforward way I came up with is to create external enum:

```
enum State {
  Running,
  Stopped,
  Broken
};
```

together with conversion functions

```
State stateEnumConv(A::B::CarInfo::State aState);
State stateEnumConv(A::B::BikeInfo::State aState);
A::B::CarInfo::State stateEnumConv(State aState);
A::B::BikeInfo::State stateEnumConv(State aState);
```

Direction into right approach is needed.

Gosh coming from C I hate those long namespaces everywhere an I wish it could be only A::B level like in presented example. Four conversion functions seem redundant note that CarInfo::State and BikeInfo::State has same enum "members".

Comment: What is generating the `enum`? What definitions are being used to indicate how they are generated? Why not create a base class and call it something like `vehicle` and define the states there?

Comment: If the state is convertible between the types, why even makes it a child type at all? Why not just use the external enum?

Comment: Also, If your stateEnumConv is in the same namespace as the classes you wouldn't need A::B:: all over the place.

Comment: Class is describing example problem. Real one represents communication framework that I would like abstract from as far as possible due inclusion problems almost everywhere in project. This file is generated based on xml files there is no possibility of changing it.

A::B namespace is different from "global" namespace State I need to import enums to parallel one.

State enum fields in CarInfo and BikeInfo are always guaranteed to stay same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use typedef or alias declaration to introduce this type.

For example

```
typedef enum {
  Running,
  Stopped,
  Broken
} State;
```

Comment: `enum State {Running,Stopped,Broken,State};` has been valid since C++98. Aliases are not needed.

Comment: I did not understood. Isn't this just introducing third type and exactly the same as what I wrote in question?

Answer (score -1):

You may use `define`

```
#define ToGeneric(vehicleInfoState) ((State) vehicleInfoState)
#define ToSpecialized(vehicleInfo, state) ((A::B::vehicleInfo::State) state)
```

example usage:

```
ToGeneric(car->getState()) // with car->getState() which returns A::B::CarInfo::Running
ToSpecialized(CarInfo, Running)
```

[Edit]
The template version seems to work too:

```
template <typename T>
State ToGeneric(typename T::State s) { return static_cast<State>(s); }

template <typename T>
typename T::State ToSpecialized(State s) { return static_cast<typename T::State>(s); }

ToGeneric<A::B::CarInfo>(carInfoState);
ToSpecific<A::B::CarInfo>(state);
```

but you have to specify the type each time (for `ToGeneric` too)

Comment: Casting the values indiscriminately is just begging for problems.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious: I agree, but OP is limited: he can't use c++11, can't modify the generator... With C++11 or generator modification, it would be possible to do better.

Comment: @Jarod42: It is good idea I thought about it. Its "C" style. Too bad I am in some automotive C++ project with many limitations especially when it comes to casting and preprocessor usage.I tend to move into direction that solution presented by me is "meh kind of ok". Additional question can I avoid redefinition of functions with almost exact same body for conversion using some template trickery?

Comment: @tomlip: in my solution, I manage all `A::B::*::State` without more code. I that answer your additional question ? (template solution added too)

Comment: @Jarod42: Thank you it is fully answering my question. I will narrow it a bit yet by using template defined conversion functions with switch case statement. Tho I really do like generic version that you wrote. Shame I cannot up vote. Now back to C++ still many things to learn especially generic types.